# cannot import name 'detail_route' from 'rest_framework.decorators'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, wagtail

I'm trying to run longclaw, but i get an error

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations catalog home

Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
 File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/longclaw/basket/api.py", line 1, in <module>
   from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route, list_route
ImportError: cannot import name 'detail_route' from 'rest_framework.decorators'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Its because `detail_route` has been deprecated from DRF 3.8. You can check their [change-log](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.8-announcement/#deprecations) as well. Alternatively, you can use `actions` decorator. For example:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action

@action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
   ....
```